# Pester InvokeVerifiable verify specific mock was called

Tags: powershell, pester

I'm struggling a bit with the `v5` Pester way of using mocks. Can anyone give me an example how I can verify that a specific mock was called via `Should -InvokeVerifiable`? And also how I can check that a specific mock was called n-times.

I also checked following Pester docu [Should InvokeVeriable](https://pester.dev/docs/commands/Should#invokeverifiable), but didn't find an answer. [Here](https://pester.dev/docs/usage/modules) I only found an example that invokes ALL mocks.

Example:

```
Describe "Describe " {

    BeforeAll {
        $localPsSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName "localhost"
        # Arrange
        Mock New-PSSession { $localPsSession } -Verifiable
        Mock Remove-PSSession -Verifiable 

        # Act -> fire the function we want to test
        ...
    }

    It "Verify that Remove-PSSession was called in Act phase" {
        # Here I want to check THAT only the Remove-PSSession mock was 
        # called and NOT the New-PSSession mock.
        # Additionally I want to check that Remove-PSSession was called e.g. 3 times
        Should -InvokeVerifiable 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Should -Invoke -CommandName <command>` to verify a specific mock versus all of those that you've marked as verifiable. You can then also use the `-Times` or `-Exactly` parameters to specify the number of times you expect that Mock to be invoked.

For your code to work you also need to move the 'Act' part inside the `It`. Example below:

```
Describe "PSSession Tests" {

    BeforeAll {
        # Arrange
        Mock New-PSSession { } -Verifiable
        Mock Remove-PSSession { } -Verifiable 
    }

    
    It "Verify that New-PSSession was called" {
        # Act
        $localPsSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName "localhost"
        
        # Assert
        Should -Invoke -CommandName New-PSSession -Times 1

    }
}
```

Note I changed the test so that it is for `New-PSSession` as that is the cmdlet that was used.

FYI there is also `Assert-MockCalled` that can be used in a similar way to validate if a specific Mock is called and how many times. The new parameters on `Should` replace this, but `Assert-MockCalled` is still in Pester v5 and can also be used.